# Reduce javascript object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flatten

I have this javascript object :

```
{
    {
        long_name: "10",
        types: [
            0: "street_number"
        ],
    },
    {
        long_name: "street",
        types: [
            0: "route"
        ],
    },
    {
        long_name: "Paris",
        types: [
            0: "locality"
        ],
    },
    ...
}
```

And I want to flatten it and have something like :

```
{
    street_number: "10",
    route: "street",
    locality: "Paris",
    ...
}
```

I am using ES6, but can't manage to flatten it this much,
All I've succeeded to do is having :

```
{
    {street_number: "10"},
    {route: "street"},
    {locality: "Paris"},
    ...
}
```

Here is what I Tried :

```
const flattenedObject = originalObject.map(flatten);
...
function flatten(element) {
    let obj = {};
    obj[element.types[0]] = element.long_name;

    return obj;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can use something like this: https://lodash.com/
Lodash has a big set of pretty useful functions, including `flatten`.

Comment: Put `let obj = {}` outside of the `flatten` method, since this is the object you want to extend. Currently, you're building a new one for each array item.

Comment: @SamedDüzçay but this has nothing do with the kind of flattening that lodash `_.flatten` does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with a [computed property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) and the first element only from the array.

The key feature is [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for adding properties to the result object.

> The `Object.assign()` method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

```js
var data = [{ long_name: "10", types: ["street_number"], }, { long_name: "street", types: ["route"], }, { long_name: "Paris", types: ["locality"], }],
    object = data.reduce((r, a) => Object.assign(r, { [a.types[0]]: a.long_name }), {});

console.log(object);
```

Comment: what does this do data.reduce((r, a)

Comment: @sacDahal, [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) takes an array and returns a value by processing all items of the array.

Answer (score 2):

> All I've succeeded to do is having:

```
{
  {street_number: "10"},
  {route: "street"},
  {locality: "Paris"},
  ...
}
```

I don't how you "succeeded" in getting that, since no such kind of object exists in JS (nor does your original object). Did you mean to put `[]` around it instead of `{}` (in other words, is it an array of little objects)? If so, then combine with

```
 Object.assign({}, ...littleObjects)
```

By the way, you can call this "flattening" if you want, but it will be confusing, since it's quite different from what people usually refer to as "flattening" (meaning to collapse nested arrays).